# jQuery CLICK event not firing (when switching to hover, it does work)

Tags: jquery, click

I have this jQuery code I've written using a click function.

The code must be working with jQuery 1.7.2.

I have a jsfiddle set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/7MpTa/1/

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    $(".balloons a").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).next('.popups').addClass("shown");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).next('.popups').removeClass("shown");
        }
    );
}
```

);

When I switch the click function to hover, it works. It's just the click function itself that doesn't work. I've tried changing it to bind, and live, but no success.

Here's a demo of the hover working: http://jsfiddle.net/8HL8k/1/

Anybody have any idea why it isn't working?

**edit**
Thanks everyone for your answers. They obviously all work great. However, when implementing these changes onto the website, the events just aren't being triggered at all (tested on FF, IE7+, Chrome, Opera, Safari). There is absolutely no other reference anywhere to the classes (balloons & popups), so I'm not sure what could cause the interference. I cannot post the link to the website because of a strict NDA policy. The  are all inside an unordered list (ul). Could it be caused by this HTML syntax? If so, are there ways around it? Because it must remain inside the  as the code is being used for hundreds of slideshows throughout the site.

I've also tried getting the anchors to send out an alert on click, to see if it would trigger it, and it didn't trigger it either.

Should the written script be called before the jQuery 1.7.2 reference inside the head or after it, or at the complete bottom of the document, before the  tag?

Answer (score 6):

You could use `toggle()` instead of `click()`:

```
$(".balloons a").toggle(
    function() {
        $(this).next('.popups').addClass("shown");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).next('.popups').removeClass("shown");
    }
);
```

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/tmzt7/

**However** keep in mind `toggle()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 and was removed in 1.9, but since you're using 1.7.2, it should work anyways...

**But**, a better solution would be to use `toggleClass()`:

```
$(".balloons a").click(
    function() {
        $(this).next('.popups').toggleClass("shown");
    }
);
```

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/GeSmx/

EDIT: answering part of your second question/issue, the jQuery reference should be before all of the methods/functions using it...

Comment: Thanks for this darkajax, it works very nicely on jsfiddle, however not when implementing onto the website. I've updated the question. Let me know if you have any thoughts as to what could be the reason why the script isn't being triggered at all. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've placed the jQuery first, on the next line, the popups script. However, it's still not triggering/working.

Comment: It's a shame you're not able to post a link to the actual website, that could be the key to figuring out the problem. Have you tried to use something like Chrome's developer tools or Firefox's Firebug check the console in case there are any errors? That's usually a good way to find out the issue...

Comment: Using Firebug, I noticed that the classes aren't being triggered. How can we check the console for errors?

Comment: Nevermind, I've just noticed it, checked the console for errors, but there aren't any.

Comment: That's odd, well you could try finding the main differences between your actual website and the jsfiddle examples, there has to be something in your website causing a problem, some other script, some other code, OR think the problem is that the actual selector `.ballons a` isn't working; if that's the case, even if you can't share the website, if you make another fiddle with the real html structure it'll be easier to determine it...

Answer (score 3):

Hover takes an on and an out function where as click takes just one function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".balloons a").click(function() {
         $(this).next('.popups').toggleClass("shown");
    });
});
```

`toggleClass` will take a step out of adding and removing the class.

Comment: This is by far the best answer because it gets at the heart of the problem (incorrectly calling the `click()` method) and a solution that isn't deprecated

Comment: Thanks for this code, Jake, it works very nicely on jsfiddle, however not when implementing onto the website. I've updated the question. Let me know if you have any thoughts as to what could be the reason why the script isn't being triggered at all. Thank you!

Comment: try commenting out everything that might be causing your problem and run the code again.  If the code runs, you know somewhere in that commented section is causing a problem.  Uncomment sections to pin point the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `toggle()` not `click`

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7MpTa/2/)

Comment: Thanks for this Muhammad, it works very nicely on jsfiddle, however not when implementing onto the website. I've updated the question. Let me know if you have any thoughts as to what could be the reason why the script isn't being triggered at all. Thank you!